# Coderwall blurred background effect with canvas

Tags: css, canvas, background

How is `coderwall.com` doing this background effect, where they take a small image, blur it, and size it up to 100% of the viewport. Here is an example: https://coderwall.com/p/on5ojq

I tried:

```
<canvas class="blur" src="https://d3levm2kxut31z.cloudfront.net/assets/locations/Mexico-1c39f581666a50a97c5130e13837ff20.jpg" width="300" height="200"></canvas>
```

Then added the following css:

```
.blur {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -2;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

But it is not working.

See the following `jsFiddle` http://jsfiddle.net/RDdbt/1/

Comment: that effect is not related to css but js, if you check their scripts you will find this link https://github.com/ceramedia/examples/blob/gh-pages/canvas-blur/v5/canvas-image.js

Comment: Tried implementing that JavaScript, but getting an error. Here is the updated jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/RDdbt/3/. Do you see the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I was able to get it working but not with the script used in your jsfiddle example.  I used the original script...  Let me know if you'd like help!

Comment: @AngeloChrysoulakis Hey, I could use some help.

Comment: @AngeloChrysoulakis - So I tried this and works pretty awesome but I've run into a strange bug and was curious if anyone else had something similar before I opened a new question: my bootstrap 3 modals occasionally don't display changes to the modal - text being typed into inputs, a progress bar being shown, etc. It might only be in chrome, and disabling this blur script fixes the issue. Anyone see anything similar?

Comment: So changing the z-index of the .blur class from -2 to 0 also fixes it, in case anyone else has this issue.

Comment: Justin thanks for asking this question — bringing this effect to my attention. It looks gorgeous, thanks @Abel Pastur for pulling together a working solution

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
var CanvasImage=function(e,t){
    this.image=t,
    this.element=e,
    this.element.width=this.image.width,
    this.element.height=this.image.height;
    var n=navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("chrome")>-1,
    r=navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")>-1;
    n&&r&&(this.element.width=Math.min(this.element.width,300),this.element.height=Math.min(this.element.height,200)),
    this.context=this.element.getContext("2d"),
    this.context.drawImage(this.image,0,0)
};

CanvasImage.prototype={
    blur:function(e){
        this.context.globalAlpha=.5;
        for(var t=-e;t<=e;t+=2)
            for(var n=-e;n<=e;n+=2)
                this.context.drawImage(this.element,n,t),
            n>=0&&t>=0&&this.context.drawImage(this.element,-(n-1),-(t-1));
            this.context.globalAlpha=1
        }
},

$(function(){
    var image,canvasImage,canvas;
    $(".blur").each(function(){
        canvas=this,
        image=new Image,
        image.onload=function(){
            canvasImage=new CanvasImage(canvas,this),
            canvasImage.blur(4)
        },
        image.src=$(this).attr("src");
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RDdbt/6/