# Recreating Medium's Image Fade Scroll Effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

Unfortunately, I'm not much of a jQuery guru, I'm trying to recreate the image fade/blur featured on medium. Here's an example -https://medium.com/matter/76d9913c6011

If you scroll down the page you'll notice some images, that progressively fade in/out as you scroll. Upon inspecting the code, I noticed there are two version of the image to create the effect, a regular version and another which has been blurred.

As far as I know, things are setup like this:

```
<section class=
"section-bottom-center section-image-full section-using-canvas"
data-scroll="native">
    <div class="section-background" data-height="2130" data-image-id=
    "1*ladXngaMeWEqp1R18uSSQA.jpeg" data-scroll="post-section" data-width=
    "3200">
        <div class="section-background-image" style=
        "background-image: url(https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/max/700/gradv/29/81/40/1*ladXngaMeWEqp1R18uSSQA.jpeg);">
        </div><br>
    </div>

    <div class="section-inner layout-single-column">
        <p>SOME TEXT THAT FADES OVER THE IMAGE</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

I found some of the jQuery, unfortunately I don't really understand it that well, so I can't recreate it.

```
var qm = function(a, b) {
  var c = '\x3cdiv class\x3d"section-background' + (a.hasFocus ? " media-has-focus" : "") + '"' + ("section-image-full" == a.imageLayout ? ' data-scroll\x3d"post-section"' : "") + 'data-image-id\x3d"' + (0,z.N)(a.backgroundImage.id) + '"', d;
  d = a.backgroundImage;
  d = (d.originalWidth ? ' data-width\x3d"' + (0,z.N)(d.originalWidth) + '"' : "") + (d.originalHeight ? ' data-height\x3d"' + (0,z.N)(d.originalHeight) + '"' : "") + (d.filter ? ' data-filter\x3d"' + (0,z.N)(d.filter) + '"' : "") + (d.backgroundSize ? ' data-image-style\x3d"' + (0,z.N)(d.backgroundSize) + '"' : "");
  c = c + d + "\x3e";
  c = "section-image-full" == a.imageLayout ? c + ('\x3cdiv class\x3d"section-background-image" style\x3d"background-image: url(' + (0,z.N)((0,z.P)(b.miroUrl)) + "/max/" + (0,z.N)("700".replace(ji, ki)) + "/gradv/29/81/40/" + (0,z.N)(String(a.backgroundImage.id).replace(ji, ki)) + ');"\x3e\x3c/div\x3e\x3cbr\x3e') : "section-image-left" == a.imageLayout || "section-image-right" == a.imageLayout ? c + ('\x3cimg src\x3d"' + (0,z.N)((0,z.P)(b.miroUrl)) + "/max/" + (0,z.N)(b.postColumnWidth) + "/multiply/grey/" + 
  (0,z.N)(a.backgroundImage.id) + '"\x3e') : c + "\x3cbr\x3e";
  return c + "\x3c/div\x3e";
};
```

One thing I did notice, is rather than the the two images simply fading in/out - the fading level is somehow bound to the scroll, so when you stop scrolling the images stop fading. This is a really nice effect.

P.S I'm looking to do this as simply as possible, preferably without jQuery plugins.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check out Andreas Storm's Medium Blur scrolling effect on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/andreasstorm/pen/pyjEh).

HTML:

```
<div class='blurImg'>
  <div style="background-image: url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/60/darken/25/1*4ncz3hLxmL8E_bUh-0z62w.jpeg')"></div>
  <div class='blur' style="background-image: url('https://d262ilb51hltx0.cloudfront.net/fit/c/1600/1280/gradv/29/81/40/darken/50/blur/50/1*4ncz3hLxmL8E_bUh-0z62w.jpeg')"></div>
</div>
<header>
  <div>
    <h1>
      Medium
    </h1>
    <p>
      Everyone’s stories and ideas
    </p>
    <a href='https://medium.com/' title='Medium'>Learn more</a>
  </div>
  <nav role='navigation'>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class='active' href='#'>Reading List</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Bookmarks</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Top 100</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<div class='container'>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body
  font-size 14px
  font-family Sans-Serif

*
  box-sizing border-box

a
  text-decoration none

.blurImg
  position relative
  width 100%
  height 440px
  z-index -1
  top 0
  left 0
  & > div
    position fixed
    width 100%
    height 440px
    background-repeat no-repeat
    background-size cover
    background-position center center

.blur
  opacity 0

header
  z-index 1
  position absolute
  top 0
  width 100%
  padding 0px 20px
  & > div
    max-width 600px
    margin 0 auto
    padding-top 150px
    height 380px
    text-align center
    color White
    a
      font-size 0.8em
      letter-spacing 0.08em
      color rgba(255,255,255,0.85)
      line-height 30px
      padding 7px 14px
      border 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.3)
      border-radius 2em
      transition all 0.3s ease
      &:hover
        background white
        color Gray
  p
    font-size 1.5em
    margin-bottom 0.7em
    font-family Times New Roman

h1
  font-weight 800
  font-size 3.4em
  margin-bottom 0.2em

nav
  max-width 600px
  margin 0 auto
  height 60px
  border-top 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.35) solid
  ul
    li
      display inline-block
      margin-right 20px
      a
        font-weight 800
        font-size 11px
        text-transform uppercase
        letter-spacing .2em
        color rgba(255,255,255,0.5)
        transition color 0.3s linear
        line-height 60px
        display block
        &.active
          box-shadow 0px -1px 0px white

nav ul li a.active, nav ul li a:hover
  color white

.container
  height 1300px
  background white
  z-index 1
  padding 0px 20px
  div
    max-width 600px
    margin 0 auto
    padding-top 40px
```

CoffeeScript:

```
$(window).scroll ->
  oVal = ($(window).scrollTop() / 240)
  $(".blur").css "opacity", oVal
```

Answer (score 0):

I also was trying to figure out how they managed this at Medium.
The minified javascript snippet you are pointing out doesn't seems to me being responsible for the blur effect. In my opinion they also process through a canvas.
Check out this SO answer:

[Coderwall blurred background effect with canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13389868/coderwall-blurred-background-effect-with-canvas)

hope that helps. (unfortunately this uses a bit of jquery but you can skip that part ;) )